# JS doughnut chart w/ percentage out of order

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

I've burned too many hours on this, so I come to you.

I'm attempting to generate a user avatar that has an SVG doughnut surrounding it that denotes the completeness of their profile as a percent.

Easy.

Unfortunately, the design calls for the percentage label to appear outside the doughnut, at the end of the stroke.

Difficult.

I figured that since the center of the circle isn't at 0,0 like it would be in a graph, I could find the x and y coords by assuming the radius is the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle, and the sum of the legs and the radius would be equal to the respective coordinates, which appears to be true. I am successfully plotting an arc in this manner

However, something is really funky with my math and the percentages appear out of order.

**This is my code:**

```
 findPercentagePosition( percentage ){
    let q = 1,
    angle = ( percentage / 100 * 360 );

    const C = 90,
    A = angle,
    B = Math.abs( C - A ), 
    c = this.arc.radius, // hypotenuse
    a = Math.abs( c * Math.sin( A ) ), //r*sin( angle )
    b = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( c, 2 ) - Math.pow( a, 2 ) ), // b^2=c^2-a^2
    CENTER = c + this.arc.strokeWidth + this.arc.offset;

    return {
        x: b + CENTER,
        y: a + CENTER
    };
}
```

**This is what happens when I try to render 0% to 24%**
[image]

Clearly I'm doing something correct(ish), because its generating an arc, but just not in the right order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigonometry functions work with radians, not degrees. A circle has 2π radians, not 360. So change it to:

```
const angle = percentage/100 * 2 * Math.PI;
const C = Math.PI/2;
```

Comment: that works, thank you! feel stupid but you saved me a whole bunch of time not realizing where I went wrong.